# List commits made by others (i.e. not me)?

Tags: git, version-control

Is there a standard way to list all the commits made by others (i.e. not myself) in a git repository?

I tried `git log --not --author=username`, but it would appear that `--not` only applies to revisions. The manpage for `git log` doesn't appear to offer a way to invert predicates like `--author`.

(I use `git-svn` at work, and want a way to see what my colleagues have changed since I last ran `git svn rebase`, or more generally in the last `X` days. Generally I know what I changed, I just want to see which files have been touched by others / read their commit log messages / maybe review interesting patches / etc.)

**Edit:** *Refined scope, I'm actually more interested in "recently" than "since last `git svn rebase`".*

Comment: It seems like you should be able to avoid this author-searching. I don't use git-svn, but `git svn rebase` is documented as fetching then rebasing, so surely it does update refs in `refs/remotes/git-svn`. Can't you just do something like `git log master@{1}..git-svn`?

Comment: I can easily see my "unpushed" patches with `git log git-svn..`, and vice-versa, but what I really want is to be able to see changes made "recently" by others, say last 3 days. Author searching seems the only way, as the commit objects / blobs and so on are rewritten by `git svn rebase`, as you say.

Comment: So again, what's wrong with `git log git-svn` or `git log master@{1}..git-svn`? Shouldn't the history look something like `-o-o-o(git-svn)-o-o-o(master)`?

Comment: @Jefromi: No problem, except that I want to filter out my own commits.

Comment: I just didn't understand why the newly fetched commits from svn would contain any of your commits. Only makes sense if it's "recently" rather than inspecting what you're fetching, as you edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a real solution, but for what it's worth, you could kludge something using the fact that `--author` uses a regex match. If your name were, say, Jefromi:

```
git log --author='^[^J]\|J[^e]\|Je[^f]' # and so on
```

It's pretty crappy, but it might be good enough for your purposes. (And it's shorter if no one else's name starts with the same letters as yours.)

As for recently, besides using branches to narrow your range (`start..end`, `^stop1 ^stop2 branch`, etc.), you can just use the `--since=<date>` option.

Comment: Not a bad idea! Do you know what flavor of regex `git log` uses?

Comment: @RobM: Git treats regex basically like grep - with all the commands that use it, it's basic regex by default, then there are `-i` (ignore case), `-E` (extended regex), and `-F` (fixed strings) options.

Answer (score 2):

```
git log --perl-regexp --author='^(?!RobM)'
```

Explanation: anchor the regexp to the beginning of the string with `^`; then use look-ahead `(?!whatever)` to forbid your name coming up after that position. This way, you can even exclude commits by several authors:

```
git log --perl-regexp --author='^(?!jack|jill)'
```