# Can gitk show all commits EXCEPT those by a given author?

Tags: git, version-control, history, author, gitk

I want to use gitk to view all commits except those by a given author. Something like the following:

*gitk --author=!joe*

Is this possible?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448000/list-commits-made-by-others-i-e-not-me

Comment: I tried the method linked here without success: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448000/list-commits-made-by-others-i-e-not-me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the command line:

```
gitk --perl-regexp --author='^(?!joe)'
```

To exclude commits by several authors:

```
gitk --perl-regexp --author='^(?!jack|jill)'
```

Explanation: `(?!whatever)` is a (perl-style) look-ahead regular expression: it matches a position not followed by `whatever`. We anchor it to the beginning of the Author field by the "beginning of string" regexp `^`.

Or run `gitk --perl-regexp` and then in the gitk menu, select View -> New View (or Shift+F4 for short) and write `^(?!joe)` into the "Author" field.

If you do not want to always have to type `gitk --perl-regexp`, you can set up git to globally use perl regular expressions by running

`git config --global grep.patternType perl`

Comment: This didn't work for me. I tried this on a Windows machine.

Comment: @Josh You're right, I did not realize that I have a global setting for perl-type regular expressions which is necessary for this to work. I edited the answer.

Comment: this does not work for me. On linux

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a terribly easy way to do it--

If you have perl or something similar, you can piece together a solution:

1. Get the list of commits you want to exclude and put them in a hash: git rev-list [refs] --author="[author pattern]"
2. Get the list of commits you want to show: git rev-list [refs]
3. Subtract the items in the hash from the commits you want to show
4. Show the commits you do want to show: gitk --no-walk [output of subtraction]

You could write something in perl/python/ruby pretty easily to do 1-3, and then just do

gitk --no-walk $(drop-author.pl [refs] [author-pattern])

Comment: This doesn't work, since gitk is set up to ignore the `--no-walk` flag